# How to map images through WP All Import to a gallery field in ACF

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm using WP All Import to import a .csv file into a custom post type. I've used ACF to create custom fields, one being a gallery field. When I'm setting up the import I can see the gallery custom field and it gives me an option to specify a Key and Value.

The gallery field in ACF has the 'field_56b48b711c3a4' for the Key Field.

Anyone got any ideas how to get the images to be mapped to the gallery custom field during the import?

Thanks

Comment: If you import the ACF records relating to this field, this should work seamlessly. (Look for the records with `acf-field` and `acf-field-group` post types in the wp_posts table)

Comment: Hi George, I can see them in the wp_posts table just not sure what I do with them. WP All Import seems to be looking for a Key and Value. is the Key ''field_56b48b711c3a4'?

Comment: got it sorted, end up using the addon for ACF